# Toolbar can't be top of CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I use'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'compile to layout, but toolbar can't be at the top of the CollapsingToolbarLayout, I don't know why. But use
Compile'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 ", toolbar can also be at the top.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovo2u.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your xml code also. Maybe there is a wrong implementation.

Well, you can this code as a base:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```